# Function arguments passed by value

Tags: javascript

I'm reading that in JavaScript, a common point of confusion arises because variables of primitives are passed by value, and variables of objects are passed by reference, while in function arguments, both primitives and references are passed by value.

In the course of my tinkering, I've made up the following code, but am having trouble wrapping my head around it.

```
> function setName2(obj) {
... obj.name="matt";
... obj = new Object();
... obj.name="obama";
... }
```

If I set

```
var person = new Object();
person.name = "michelle";
```

Then run

```
> setName2(person);
```

I get

```
> person.name;
'matt'
```

Which makes sense because the new object created is a pointer to a local object, hence not affecting the property of the global 'person'.

However, what if I first set

```
 var obj = new Object();
    obj.name = "michelle";
```

Then run

```
  > setName2(obj);
```

?

I get the same outcome. Does this mean that the compiler recognizes the two variables of the same name (obj global and obj local) as references to different locations within the heap, each having some different pointer association, or is there a different explanation for this phenomenon?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript does not have pass-by-reference; *everything* is passed by value. However, some values are themselves references to objects. This distinction (pass-by-reference vs. is-a-reference) leads to much confusion.

An example to clear things up:

```
function f(o) { ... }
var obj = { foo: 42 };
f(obj);
```

No matter what you do in `f`, `obj` will always refer to the same object because the argument is not *passed by reference*. However the value `obj`, which is copied into `o`, *is itself a reference* to an object. This is why any property changes made to `o` inside the function will be visible on `obj` after it returns.

Answer (score 1):

> while in function arguments, both primitives and references are passed by value.

This is not true. There is nothing special about function arguments.

```
function setName2(obj) {
```

This accepts a reference to an object as an argument.

```
obj.name="matt";
```

This modifies the `name` property of the object that reference points to.

```
obj = new Object();
```

This replaces the reference to the original object with a reference to a new object.

```
obj.name="obama";
```

This modifies the name property of the new object. The original object is unchanged.

Comment: Here's an excerpt from "Professional Javascript for Web Developers" by  Zakas which led me to that statement: "All function arguments in ECMAScript are passed by value. This means that the value outside of the function is copied into an argument on the inside of the function the same way a value is copied from one variable to another. If the value is primitive, then it acts just like a primitive variable copy, and if the value is a reference, it acts just like a reference variable copy.

Comment: This is often a point of confusion for developers, because variables are accessed both by value and by reference, but arguments are passed only by value."

Answer (score 1):

The confusion comes from the fact that "passed by reference" is misinterpreted by people or used in a wrong sense.

Parameters are passed by value. This means that changing the value inside the method doesn't change the original value.

In case of primitives, the value of a primitive is its value.
In case of objects, the value of an object is a reference to it. You can access and change object's content but you can't change the value of the reference itself.

In other programming languages, like C++ or C#, "passing by reference" means that you pass:
- a reference to a primitive type
- a reference to a reference to an object
In such case, not only the content of an object can be changed but also a reference itself can be changed.

There is NO passing by reference in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript uses **pass-by-value**.

The confusion is that objects are hold by reference variables (kind of pointers). In fact most common languages (java, javascript, etc.) do not have a real pass-by-reference behaviour. Another way to understand this could be **pass-reference-by-value**, although, formally, there is not such a thing.

That means when you pass an object as a parameter, you are actually **passing a reference to the object *by-value***.

```
function setName2(obj) {
  ...
}

setName2(person);
```

here the contents of `person` (a reference, or "pointer" if you like) is copied *by-value* to a new local variable: `obj`.

`obj` and `person` are different variables that hold a reference to the same object.

So, doing `obj = new Object();` makes `obj` to point to the new object. But `person` is unaffected since it is still a completely different variable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you read that, but it's absolutely not true. Objects are passed by reference, full stop. Whether or not it's a function parameter is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Saying that "objects are passed by reference" is the source of confusion. It is better to say that everything is passed by value but what value is depends on whether it is a primitive or an object.